# Unable to crop the ROI from original image

Tags: java, android-studio, opencv, image-processing

I'm unable to crop the ROI  into the original  image after finding rectangle boundaries. Instead of showing the cropped image, it displays the contour and rectangle boundary instead. My main goal is to crop inner square from the circular sample for further processing using Pythagorean Theorem: the diagonal of a square is root of 2 times the lenghth of a side. Please help as I'm new to openCV

```
  public void imageProcessingAlgorithm (){
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              long tStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
              countWBC = 0;
              countRBC = 0;

              //Convert the Bitmap image to Mat
              //Utils.bitmapToMat converts an Android Bitmap to an OpenCV Mat.
              Mat oriImage = new Mat();
              Utils.bitmapToMat(processBitmap, oriImage);
              //Imgproc.cvtColor(oriImage, oriImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

              //Grayscale image
              Mat grayscale = new Mat();
              Imgproc.cvtColor(oriImage,grayscale, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

              //Otsu Thresholding (Binary Image)
              Mat otsuThreshold = new Mat();
              Imgproc.threshold(grayscale, otsuThreshold ,0,255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);

              //Contour finding
              List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>(); //list for contours
              Imgproc.findContours(otsuThreshold, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
              //Mat drawing = new Mat(otsuThreshold.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3);

              Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
              Rect rect = new Rect();
              int xBound =0;
              int yBound =0;
              int xWidth =0;
              int yHeight =0;
              int radius = 0;

              for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
                  Mat contour = contours.get(idx);
                  List<Double> areasList = new ArrayList<Double>(); //list for area
                  double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
                  areasList.add(contourarea);
                  //POint2f means 2D coordinates
                  MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
                  MatOfPoint2f contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(idx).toArray());
                  double approxDistance = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f, true) * 0.02;
                  Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contour2f, approxCurve, approxDistance, true);
                  MatOfPoint points = new MatOfPoint(approxCurve.toArray());
                  rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(points);
                  if (contourarea > 100000) {

                      //Contour Drawing + Bounding Box
                      xBound = rect.x;
                      yBound = rect.y;
                      xWidth = rect.width;
                      yHeight = rect.height;
                      //to Draw contour(colour is in Red)
                      Imgproc.drawContours(oriImage, contours, idx, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, new Point());
                      //to Draw Outer Bounding rectangle(colour is in Green)
                      Imgproc.rectangle(oriImage, new Point(rect.x, rect.y),
                              new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
                      if (rect.height > rect.width)
                          radius = rect.width/2;
                      else
                          radius = rect.height/2;
                  }
              }

              //To find internal boundary to crop image
              radius = (int)(radius*0.70711);
              int xPos = xBound+(xWidth/2)-radius;
              int yPos = yBound+(yHeight/2)-radius;
              Rect reg_info = new Rect(xPos,yPos,radius*2,radius*2);
              Mat roi = oriImage.submat(reg_info);



              // CIELab conversion

              long tEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
          long tDelta = tEnd - tStart;
          elapsedSeconds = tDelta/1000.0 ;

          //To convert the Mat object back to Bitmap
          Utils.matToBitmap(roi,processBitmap);


        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                PhotoView myImage = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.resultImage);
                myImage.setImageBitmap(processBitmap);
                db.updateResult(new SampleViewList(fileName,folderName,countRBC,countWBC,String.valueOf(elapsedSeconds),getDate()));
                getImage = db.getImgView(fileName);
                showResult();
                try{
                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(resultImagedir);
                    processBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
                    try{
                        fOut.flush();
                        fOut.close();
                    } catch (IOException E){
                        E.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

  }

  });
          }
}).start();
  }
```

[image]

result image on RHS

Comment: Sounds like you are cropping the image you are drawing onto. Either do not draw to it before cropping or create a deep copy before drawing the info and crop that image instead.